# Not able to run my Firebase Unity App

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I just wanted to test my Firebase implementation and realized that I get an error saying that Unity can't find the generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe even though it is where it should be.

Entire Error:

```
Unable to find command line tool D:/Philipp's D Dokumente/Coding/C#/Unity/Multi-Case Clicker/Assets\..\Assets\Firebase\Editor\generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe required for Firebase Android resource generation.
D:/Philipp's D Dokumente/Coding/C#/Unity/Multi-Case Clicker/Assets\..\Assets\Firebase\Editor\generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe is required to generate the Firebase Android resource file google-services.xml from Assets/google-services.json. Without Firebase Android resources, your app will fail to initialize.
D:/Philipp's D Dokumente/Coding/C#/Unity/Multi-Case Clicker/Assets\..\Assets\Firebase\Editor\generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe was distributed with each Firebase Unity SDK plugin, was it deleted?

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='D:/Philipp's D Dokumente/Coding/C#/Unity/Multi-Case Clicker/Assets\..\Assets\Firebase\Editor\generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe', CommandLine='-i "Assets/google-services.json" -l', CurrentDirectory='D:\Philipp's D Dokumente\Coding\C#\Unity\Multi-Case Clicker'
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
  at GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.RunViaShell (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 envVars, GooglePlayServices.IOHandler ioHandler, Boolean useShellExecution, Boolean stdoutRedirectionInShellMode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GooglePlayServices.CommandLine.Run (System.String toolPath, System.String arguments, System.String workingDirectory, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 envVars, GooglePlayServices.IOHandler ioHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson.RunResourceGenerator (System.String arguments, System.String inputPath, Boolean showCommandLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:RunResourceGenerator(String, String, Boolean)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:ReadBundleIds(String)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:ReadBundleIdsFromGoogleServicesFiles()
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:UpdateJsonWithBundleIdChooserDialog(String, Boolean)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:CheckConfiguration()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Also when I try to Force-Resolve I get this:

```
Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:4.2.0@aar
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:4.2.0@aar


UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:LogDelegate(String, LogLevel)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, LogLevel, Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:LogMissingDependenciesError(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey4:<>m__1(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Comment: I'll bet it is the "apostrophe" in the pathname.

Comment: @jdv it literally was the apostrophe. I don't get the error anymore. Well now all I have to do is fix my code lol. Thanks for the help!